# Inequality bound using endpoints?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Currently reading [Introduction to Calculus and Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/354065058X) by Richard Courant. On page 42 Courant uses the following fact in a larger example explaining why $x^2$ is not uniform continuous (where $a$ and $b$ are the endpoints of the closed interval of interest).

$$|x - x_0| |x + x_0| \space \leq \space 2 \space |x-x_0| \space (|b| + |a|)$$

**So my question is why does this work? It is not clear to me why $|x + x_0| \leq 2 \space (|b| + |a|)$ is true.**

Not sure if this will help, but I've included the relevant parts of the textbook. Any help would be appreciated.

> The function $f(x) = x^2$ for an infinite $x$-interval is definitely not uniform continuous. It is clear that small changes in x can produce arbitrarily large changes in $x^2$ if only $x$ is large enough. A glance at a table of squares of integers $x$ shows how successive squares are spaced further and further apart as $x$ increases. If, however, we only consider pairs of values $x$ and $x_0$ belonging to a fixed finite closed interval $[a, b]$, we can find a uniform modulus of continuity. Indeed, for $|x - x_0| < \delta$ we have
>
> $$|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |x^2 - x_0^2| = |x - x_0| |x + x_0| \space \leq \space 2 \space |x-x_0| \space (|b| + |a|)$$
>
> $$< 2 \delta (|b| + |a|) = \epsilon$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now $x,x_0$ are both in the interval $[a,b]$ thus they are both a convex combination of endpoints, so
$$
x=\theta a+(1-\theta)b,\quad x_0=\alpha a+(1-\alpha)b,\quad \theta,\alpha \in [0,1].$$

Now sum $x$ and $x_0$ and apply the triangle inequality to obtain the result. Specifically
$$|x+x_0| \leq |a|(|\alpha|+|\theta|) + |b||2-\theta-\alpha|\leq 2(|a|+|b|)$$
since we know $\theta$ and $\alpha$ are in $[0,1]$ thus
$$(|\alpha|+|\theta|)\leq 2\quad and\quad|2-\alpha-\theta|\leq 2.$$

Comment: So $|x+x_0| \leq |a|(|\alpha|+|\theta|) + |b||2-\theta-\alpha| \leq |a|(1+1) + |b|(2)$...ok your answer is good.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo, see my edit. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand your explanation

Answer (score 0):

For $y\in [a,b]$, we have $|y|\leq\max(|a|,|b|)$. Indeed, if $y\geq 0$, then $|y|\leq b=|b|$, and if $y<0$, then $y\geq a$, which implies $|y|\leq |a|$ (since $a$ is also negative). In total, $|y|\leq\max(|a|,|b|)$.

But $\max(|a|,|b|) \leq |a|+|b|$. Indeed, no matter which of $|a|$ and $|b|$ is larger, it will still be less than the sum $|a|+|b|$.

In conclusion, since $x,x_0\in [a,b]$, we have
$$|x+x_0|\leq |x|+|x_0|\leq 2\max(|a|,|b|)\leq 2(|a|+|b|).$$